# Double text shadow on p element in CSS3

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to apply two `text-shadow` values on one `p` element with CSS3?
I want to create a very light black `background` with a 1 pixel `border`.

Something like this:

```
text-shadow: 0 0 55px black; (very light black background to increase white text readabilitiy)
&
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0, .25); (one pixel black drop shadow)
```

Comment: Could you not store both shadows in a class each and apply them to the necessary p tags?

Comment: you can even create 3D text with `text-shadow` just by combining some text-shadows in a comma separated list, someone has already done some example out there, just search yourself to see `text-shadow` in action.

Comment: @Aaron Lee, the last class will override the other. You must have all effects in one and same comma separated text-shadow statement. Preseding text-shadow is ignored.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can simply seperate the shadows with a comma:

`text-shadow: 0 0 55px black, 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0, .25);`

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/98E9s/)

You may want to [have a look at this article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-shadow) for further information.

> The text-shadow CSS property adds shadows to text. It accepts a
>   comma-separated list of shadows to be applied to the text and
>   text-decorations of the element.
>
> Each shadow is specified as an offset from the text, along with
>   optional color and blur radius values.
>        Multiple shadows are applied front-to-back, with the first-specified shadow on top.

Comment: Ah sweet, I was trying text-shadow: 0 0 55px black, text-shadow: ... and that (obviously) didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: Seems like this method doesn't work in Safari (on OSX). Result on Safari: http://d.pr/i/U6bp Result on Chrome: http://d.pr/i/xT20 Chrome does have the very light box shadow, Safari takes it differently. Any solution? Used code: text-shadow: 0 0 55px rgba(0,0,0, .5), 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0, .25);

Comment: You'll need to look for a Javascript solution, e.g. http://www.hintzmann.dk/testcenter/js/jquery/textshadow/

Answer (score 3):

You can try using this code :

```
p { text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000, 3px 3px 5px blue; }
```

REF : [CSS SHADOW TRICKS](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-text-shadow/)