# Can I make a text that already has a shadow glow?

Tags: css

Pretty simple question to which an answer was elusive when I searched.

I have text with the shadow property already defined. I want to make the text itself glow faintly though (not on hover, but by default). Is there a way to do this in CSS only, or do I need to use javascript? I don't really care if the shadow too glows or doesn't glow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22168574/648350 heres an answer.. and an updated fiddle that you can adjust to your needs: http://jsfiddle.net/98E9s/5/

Comment: oh dear god that is fantastically simple, thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Double text shadow on p-tag in CSS3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22168506/double-text-shadow-on-p-tag-in-css3)